# отображение элементов в xml файле

Tags: android, activity

Добавил для кнопок свой дизайн, и они стали прозрачные на экране с дизайном, на blueprint они есть. В чем проблема ?

[image: roid]

Это `xml` самого окна приложения:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:textColor="#3498db"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:maxLength="6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegistration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/contour_button"
    android:text="Регистрация"
    android:textColor="#3498db"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAuthorization"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/contour_button"
    android:text="Авторизация"
    android:textColor="#3498db"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="normal" />
```

Это xml файл дизайна кнопки :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может цвет фона и цвет текста одинаковые?

Comment: В таких случаях нужно показывать не только скрин, но xml файлы.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev добавил !

Comment: @pavlofff добавил код!

Comment: На окне с дизайном - это где? Андроид Студия?

Comment: @Эникейщик да. Есть Design , и есть Blueprint